# Getting ErrorItemNotFound

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar, outlook-calendar

I am using graph api for outlook calendars.
Frequently I am getting ({"error":{"code":"ErrorItemNotFound","message":"The specified object was not found in the store.","innerError":{"date":"2022-10-06T04:31:59","request-id":"e1682a2b-eeed-4f34-9c55-218f5af8e83c","client-request-id":"e1682a2b-eeed-4f34-9c55-218f5af8e83c"}}})

The call I am making is
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/#{event_id}?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,start,end,recurrence,showAs](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/#%7Bevent_id%7D?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,start,end,recurrence,showAs)

Where
event_id is the id I get in request ["resourceData"]["id"] from outlook push notification.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

When we tried to repo the same ,the API is working fine , could you please try to get list to events Fist with API - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events , then try to select the available id , and then try with [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{event_id}?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,start,end,recurrence,showAs](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/%7Bevent_id%7D?$select=subject,body,bodyPreview,start,end,recurrence,showAs)

[image]

**Note**: In your URL ,you added # before event_id , i am assuming that was just a typo , make sure you are calling the correct API

Hope this helps

Thanks